# What does it mean to "pin a badge" on something?

Tags: idioms

Original sentence was:

Linux Foundation Wants to Pin a Badge on Secure Open Source Software

Thanks

Comment: Pin badges are used as a fashion accessory, to display accomplishment or show a level of authority. A colourful, standout item like a badge draws the eye.

Answer (score 2):

"Pin a badge" is simple: it means to "stick a badge" on something. Often in public meetings, including those held in India, the supporters of a particular party sport badge on the left side of the chest. They stick the badge with their shirts (or whatever they wear) with the help of a safety pin. The idea behind is: let the others know who in the meeting are supporting the particular party (or a particular cause that the party is espousing). This is "pinning the badge".